# Grunt refuses to create a custom.min.css file

Tags: gruntjs

I'm currently learning how to use PostCSS with Grunt in one of my classes. Asked my professor if they could help me, they said the Gruntfile.js looked fine, but maybe the issue was my file name being lowercase. I changed it to Gruntfile.js and am receiving the same error. It is automatically supposed to create the custom.min.css, but due to the error (located below), it does not. I contacted my professor, but it seems that we've hit a dead-end.

Every time I create the JS file for Grunt, save it in the correct folder, and I run grunt in my Command Prompt, I receive the following error:

> C:\Users\name\Desktop\grunt-boilerplate>
> Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>
> > Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
> > Aborted due to warnings.

My JS coding looks like this:

```
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

      postcss: {
    options: {
        processors: [
            require('pixrem')(), // add fallbacks for rem units
            require('autoprefixer')({
                browsers: 'last 2 versions'
            }), // add vendor prefixes
            require('cssnano')() // minify the result
        ]
    },
    dist: {
        src: 'css/custom.css',
        dest: 'css/custom.min.css',
    }
}
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['postcss']);

};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### Error loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks

As for the error in the terminal, it seems like you're missing this line at the start of the file:
`module.exports = function (grunt) {`

See: https://gruntjs.com/getting-started#an-example-gruntfile

Now about the first problem.

### Packages

First of all, check the correct installation of all your node modules.

1. Open your terminal
2. `cd` to your project root, where the `package.json` is located
3. Do `npm install`
4. Do `npm install autoprefixer grunt grunt-postcss pixrem cssnano --save-dev`

### Autoprefixer usage

You are probably using the autoprefixer plugin in a wrong way: you need to move the `browsers` option into your `package.json` file:

`Gruntfile.js`

```js
...
processors: [
    require('pixrem')(),
    // No autoprefixer 'browsers' option
    require('autoprefixer')(),
    require('cssnano')()
]
...
```

`package.json`

```js
{
    ...
    // 'browserslist' option at the end of the file just above the last curly brace
    'browserslist': [
        'last 4 versions',
        '> 0.5%'
    ]
}
```

See: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browserslist-

### Changing `dist` property

You could try changing your `dist` syntax using `files` property:

```js
...
dist: {
    // src: 'css/custom.css',
    // dest: 'css/custom.min.css',
    files: {
        'css/custom.min.css': 'css/custom.css'
    }
}
...
```

### Summary

The whole `Gruntfile.js` should look something like that:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        // This is probably a leftover from the example Gruntfile.js
        // pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        postcss: {
            options: {
                processors: [
                    require('pixrem')(),
                    // No autoprefixer 'browsers' option
                    require('autoprefixer')(),
                    require('cssnano')()
                ]
            },
            dist: {
                // src: 'css/custom.css',
                // dest: 'css/custom.min.css',
                files: {
                    'css/custom.min.css': 'css/custom.css'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['postcss']);
};
```